# The number of words in which the relative order of vowels and consonants remain unchanged.

Tags: combinatorics

If as many more words as possible be formed out of the letters of the word $DOGMATIC$ then compute the number of words in which the relative order of vowels and consonants remain unchanged.

---

Since the position of vowels and consonants is not to be changed,so the total ways are $3!\times 5!=720$
But the answer given is $719.$

Comment: What is a word? In addition, presumably each letter must be used exactly once? I'm not entirely sure what is meant by 'the relative order of vowels and consonants remain unchanged' - does this mean the word must have $OAI$ and $DGMTC$ in that order?

Comment: The way I interpret the problem statement, the answer would be ${8\choose 3}=56$, with valid words in alphabetical order being DGMOAITC, DGMOATIC, DGMOATCI, DGMOTAIC, DGMOTACI, ..., ODGMTCAI. However, your answer seems to count all words with consonant-vowel pattern CVCCVCVC, and the answer given seems to not count the original word.

Comment: Also, would it be possible to give the origin of this question? It is possible that $DOGMATIC$ is not counted, if your interpretation is correct (although to me, that would be an error by the question setter, given the wording).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the answer will be $719$ because you have to find the the number of new words formed since the question says,”as many more words as possible”. $720$ is the count including DOGMATIC, therefore new words formed will be $720-1=719$.